# Ghostscript eps file conversion to jpg not working inside the .NET application

Tags: c#, .net, ghostscript, eps, image-conversion

I am working on a project a .NET application which generates preview and thumbnail images with the help of imagemagick and Irfanview applications. Since Imagemagick not supporting the conversion of .eps format files, I have tried using Ghostscript GPL v10.02.1 in the project. So I have tried the following command inside the bin folder of the ghostscript application in my local machine and it has successfully converted the file from .eps to .jpg format. But when I used the same arguments in the project it is not working, it always returns the exit code as 1. The arguments I have used:

gswin64c.exe -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pngalpha -dEPSCrop -r300 -sOutputFile=output.png EPS.eps

````I have tried this code below but `ghostscriptResult` always returns exit code as 1, but expects 0.

```
 bool isEps = string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(image.Filename), ".eps", true) == 0;
 string epsFilePath = image.Filename;
 string jpgOutputPath = Path.Combine(PreviewLocation, Path.ChangeExtension(Path.GetFileName(image.Filename), ".jpg"));
 string ghostscriptCommand = string.Format(GhostscriptArguments, epsFilePath, jpgOutputPath);
 var ghostscriptResult = RunProcess(WorkingDirectory, GhostscriptPath, ghostscriptCommand, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
```

Comment: Please edit your post so it's formatted usefully - use the preview to check that the post looks how you want it to look before hitting "submit".

Comment: If it works from the command line then it isn't Ghostscript which is the problem. Try printing out the GhostscriptPath and ghostscriptComnmand to make sure those are correct. To be honest I don't see this as either a question about EPS or Ghostscript, if it works from the command line then it must be your RunProcess which is at fault, surely.